# How can I use babel 6 with pm2 1.0?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, pm2

I have server code written in ES6, and I use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) to manage that server.
A few months ago, I used the `next_gen_js` option and it worked magically.

However, I now tried to update pm2 to v1.0.0, and I get errors about `import` being an illegal token. Basically, my ES6 files are not parsed as ES6 anymore.

What can I do to use pm2 with ES6 files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pm2 [dropped](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1468#issuecomment-167764109) the `next_gen_js` flag in v1.0.0, because it bundled babel, which was quite heavy.

You basically have four options.

1. Stop using ES6 on your backend.
2. Stick to pm2 v0.14 and use the `next_gen_js` flag.
3. Use the `interpreter` (alias of `exec_interpreter`) flag and set it to `babel-node`. You'll need to add `babel-cli` as a dependency of your app. Note that the `interpreter` option is compatible only with the `fork` `exec_mode`, not with `cluster`. This option being still in beta at the time of writing, this might not be a major issue unless you have important scaling constraints.
4. Use some specific entry point that first requires [`babel-register`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/). For example, you might have a `server.js` file that's in ES6 and the preferred entry point for ES6-compatible engines, and an `index.js` that only does `require('babel-register'); require('./server');`.

Answer (score -3):

From the documentation (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/), you just start pm2 with an interpreter tag like:

```
pm2 start --interpreter babel-node server.js //(server.es6)
```